# Sliding max window and its average for multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a `60 x 21 x 700` matrix, where the `60 x 21` represent a `pressure output` x `number of frames`. I want to find the `2 x 2` window that generates the maximum average pressure per frame and store it in a new variable so that it can be plotted. For example, if the matrix looked something like this:

```
01 02 02 01 01
02 01 01 02 02
02 03 04 04 03
01 02 06 10 05
02 02 08 09 05
```

The max window and its average for a `2 x 2` window would be -

```
06 10
08 09

= 8.25
```

So far in my search for a solution I've only been able to find a way to get the max value (eg. `10` from the matrix above), but really can't work out how to get the max average from a small area that doesn't have a fixed index to reference. I'm fairly new to MATLAB, so my apologies if I've missed something or am simply not understanding things correctly.
Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The dimensions of the matrix isn't divisible by `2`. what do you want to do for that?

Comment: @SanthanSalai, I think the OP is thinking about a 'sliding' average, so the matrix size doesn't have to be an exact multiple of the window size. Gumajin, could you confirm or infirm this please.

Comment: @Hoki Yes, I think that would be the closest to what I'm trying to achieve. Sorry if my question wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**2D Arrays:** For the given 2D array input, you can use [`2D convolution`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) -

```
%// Perform 2D convolution with a kernel of `2 x 2` size with all ones
conv2_out = conv2(A,ones(2,2),'same')

%// Find starting row-col indices of the window that has the maximum conv value
[~,idx] = max(conv2_out(:))
[R,C] = ind2sub(size(A),idx)

%// Get the window with max convolution value
max_window = A(R:R+1,C:C+1)

%// Get the average of the max window
out =  mean2(max_window)
```

Sample step-by-step run of the code -

```
A =
     1     2     2     1     1
     2     1     1     2     2
     2     3     4     4     3
     1     2     6    10     5
     2     2     8     9     5
conv2_out =
     6     6     6     6     3
     8     9    11    11     5
     8    15    24    22     8
     7    18    33    29    10
     4    10    17    14     5
idx =
    14
R =
     4
C =
     3
max_window =
     6    10
     8     9
out =
         8.25
```

---

**Multi-dimensional Arrays:** For multi-dimensional array case, you need to perform [`ND convolution`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html) -

```
%// Perform ND convolution with a kernel of 2 x 2 size with all ONES
conv_out = convn(A,ones(2,2),'same')

%// Get the average for all max windows in all frames/slices  
[~,idx] = max(reshape(conv_out,[],size(conv_out,3)),[],1)
max_avg_vals = conv_out([0:size(A,3)-1]*numel(A(:,:,1)) + idx)/4

%// If needed, get the max windows across all dim3 slices/frames
nrows = size(A,1)
start_idx = [0:size(A,3)-1]*numel(A(:,:,1)) + idx
all_idx = bsxfun(@plus,permute(start_idx(:),[3 2 1]),[0 nrows;1 nrows+1])
max_window = A(all_idx)
```

Sample input, output -

```
>> A
A(:,:,1) =
     4     1     9     9
     3     7     5     5
     9     6     1     6
     7     1     1     5
     4     2     2     1
A(:,:,2) =
     9     4     2     2
     3     6     4     5
     3     9     1     1
     6     6     8     8
     5     3     6     4
A(:,:,3) =
     5     5     7     7
     6     1     9     9
     7     7     5     4
     4     1     3     7
     1     9     3     1
>> max_window
max_window(:,:,1) =
     9     9
     5     5
max_window(:,:,2) =
     8     8
     6     4
max_window(:,:,3) =
     7     7
     9     9
>> max_avg_vals
max_avg_vals =
            7          6.5            8
```

Comment: I was about to type exactly the same. I think its the most efficient way, as `conv2` turned out to be very fast in the past.

Comment: damn you always beat me on these one ! Good job ;-)

Comment: @Hoki Sorry! :) Well as it turns out we don't even need to find average in each window.

Comment: Thanks very much. So if I wanted to calculate this for all 700 frames, would putting in a for loop work?

Comment: Note if you use `valid` instead of `same` for the convolution output option you don't have to discard the last line and column (because they are only the average of 2 values and not 4).

Comment: @Hoki You are right, saves on a bit of memory there.

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I ask you one last question. When I run the code, it chooses the frame with the highest pressure and returns the average for that frame only. Is there a way to store the results from each frame in the ND matrix? Or would it be better to split the data into 2D and work from there?

Comment: @Gumajin Check out the edits please. No looping or splitting needed.

Answer (score 3):

A moving average can be done with a simple convolution. It has to be 2D in your case, so:

```
A = [01 02 02 01 01
     02 01 01 02 02
     02 03 04 04 03
     01 02 06 10 05
     02 02 08 09 05];

B = [1 1;1 1] / 4 ; %// prepare moving average filter [2x2]

C = conv2(A,B,'valid') ; %// perform 2D moving average
```

Produces:

```
C =
    1.5     1.5     1.5     1.5
    2       2.25    2.75    2.75
    2       3.75    6       5.5
    1.75    4.5     8.25    7.25
```

Which is exactly the average of each of your [2x2] areas.

Answer (score 2):

One other approach using [`im2col`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html)

```
%// getting each 2x2 sliding submatrices as columns
cols = im2col(A,[2 2],'sliding'); 

%// getting the mean & reshaping it to 2D matrix
C = reshape(mean(cols),size(A,1)-1,[]); 

%// to find the maximum of the sub-matrix-means and its corresponding index.
[B,i] = max(mean(cols)); 

%// reshaping the corresponding sub-matrix to 2D matrix
mat = reshape(cols(:,i),2,2);
```

Results:

```
>> mat

mat =

 6    10
 8     9

>> C

C =

1.5000    1.5000    1.5000    1.5000
2.0000    2.2500    2.7500    2.7500
2.0000    3.7500    6.0000    5.5000
1.7500    4.5000    8.2500    7.2500

>> B

B =

8.2500
```