# Vectorized function to find extrema in 3D array (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, max, vectorization, minimum

I have a 3D matrix `A` in Matlab. I want to find the local extrema (minima and maxima) in this matrix, using a 3x3x3 moving window. That is, I want all indices `i,j,k` that satisfy

```
tmp = A(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1,k-1:k+1)
A(i,j,k) == min(tmp(:)) || A(i,j,k) == max(tmp(:))
```

I have a script using nested for loops (see below) to find the extrema using the criteria above. I'm just wondering if there is a way to vectorize the operation.

I should also mention that the boundaries are periodic; for example, at the point `{i,j,k} = {1,1,1}`, the evaluation should be

```
tmp = A([end,1,2],[end,1,2],[end,1,2])
A(1,1,1) == min(tmp(:)) || A(1,1,1) == max(tmp(:))
```

The aforementioned script is below:

```
s = size(A);

% Make outer boundaries equal
A1 = [A(end,:,:); A; A(1,:,:)];
A1 = [A1(:,end,:), A1, A1(:,1,:)];
A2 = NaN(s + [2 2 2]);
A2(:,:,1) = A1(:,:,end);
A2(:,:,2:end-1) = A1;
A2(:,:,end) = A1(:,:,1);

% Create arrays to record extrema
minvals = false(s); maxvals = minvals;

for i = 2:s(1)+1
    for j = 2:s(2)+1
        for k = 2:s(3)+1
            tmp = A2(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1,k-1:k+1);
            a = A2(i,j,k);
            if a == min(tmp(:))
                minvals(i-1,j-1,k-1) = true;
            end
            if a == max(tmp(:))
                maxvals(i-1,j-1,k-1) = true;
            end
        end
    end
end

[MINidc.i, MINidc.j, MINidc.k] = ind2sub(s,find(minvals));
[MAXidc.i, MAXidc.j, MAXidc.k] = ind2sub(s,find(maxvals));
```

Comment: How large is your matrix? Vectorizing this (I am not sure how at the moment) would require to create an individual row for each call of max. This would blow up your data by a factor of 27. Is this feasible or would it exceed the memory?

Comment: See if [`Sliding max window and its average for multi-dimensional arrays`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072284/sliding-max-window-and-its-average-for-multi-dimensional-arrays) helps.

Comment: @Daniel In my particular case it wouldn't be an issue. In fact, the for-loop implementation works quickly enough. It's more for curiosity sake that I ask. So let's go with the assumption that the 27-fold increase in memory isn't a problem.

Comment: @Divakar: I don't see a connection to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would vectorize this:

```
s=size(A);
s2=cumprod(s);
%For all indices 1:numel(a) build up a table with the neibours among 1. dimension
x=bsxfun(@plus,(1:numel(A)).',cat(2,-1,0,1));
%and second dimension
x=bsxfun(@plus,x,cat(3,-s2(1),0,s2(1)))
%and third dimension
x=bsxfun(@plus,x,cat(4,-s2(2),0,s2(2)));
%reshape to have one row for each element
x=reshape(x,[],27);
%wrap around borders
x=mod(x-1,numel(A))+1;
%use index matrix to get a matrix of values
B=A(x);
%the 14th element is the center of a 27 element cube.
local_maxima=max(B,[],2)==B(:,14);
local_minima=min(B,[],2)==B(:,14);
[MINidc.i, MINidc.j, MINidc.k] = ind2sub(s,find(local_minima));
[MAXidc.i, MAXidc.j, MAXidc.k] = ind2sub(s,find(local_maxima));
```

The idea is to build up a matrix first which contains all indices which are neighbours of an element. If you intend to understand the code, replace the `(1:numel(A)).'` with the linear index of the element `A(2,2,2)` which creates the cube `A(1:3,1:3,1:3)`.

Comment: Nice. For a 30x30x30 test matrix with five extrema, your code runs about 80% faster than mine.